# library dependencies

Tags: ros, catkin, add-dependencies, dependencies, libraries

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a catkin library that I'm trying to edit the CMakeLists.txt file for so it builds a package containing services before it compiles the package.

I just learned that in order to do this for a regular package of executables, you use the `add_dependencies()` keywords in Cmake.  How do you go about doing this for a library?

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(baxter_kinematics)

find_package(cmake_modules REQUIRED)

find_package(Eigen REQUIRED)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  std_msgs
  sensor_msgs
  tf
  cwru_srv
)

include_directories(
  ${Eigen_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${PROJECT_NAME}/include
)

add_definitions(${EIGEN_DEFINITIONS})

SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++0x")

catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include 
  LIBRARIES ${PROJECT_NAME}
  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp std_msgs sensor_msgs tf baxter_core_msgs cwru_srv
  DEPENDS eigen system_lib
)

include_directories(
  include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_library(
  ${PROJECT_NAME}
  src/baxter_kinematics.cpp
 )

## Declare a cpp executable

add_executable(baxter_kinematics_test_main src/baxter_kinematics_test_main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(baxter_kinematics_test_main baxter_kinematics ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

## ???
## add_dependencies(baxter_kinematics cwru_srv)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/218063/library-dependencies/) by [luc](https://answers.ros.org/users/18958/luc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 350 on 2015-09-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-09-23**:
Isn't this a duplicate of [having to compile msgs and srvs first](http://answers.ros.org/question/218048/having-to-compile-msgs-and-srvs-first/)?

The linked docs show you this:

> ```
> add_dependencies(your_library ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
> ```

Which completely answers your question.

**Comment by [luc](https://answers.ros.org/users/18958/luc/) on 2015-09-23**:
Sure does.  I should probably slow down a bit.. Haha, sorry about that again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think I got it to work by actually just un-commenting the last line (kinda)

`add_dependencies(baxter_kinematics cwru_srv_gencpp)`

If somebody can confirm that this is how it's done, that'd be swell.

---

Originally posted by [luc](https://answers.ros.org/users/18958/luc/) with karma: 350 on 2015-09-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mani](https://answers.ros.org/users/1858/mani/) on 2015-09-22**:
I believe this is correct since `add_dependency()` creates dependencies between targets (either executable target or libraries).

**Comment by [luc](https://answers.ros.org/users/18958/luc/) on 2015-09-22**:
Awesome, thanks.